# Are staff members considering our requests to reintroduce the "last seen" metrics?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation

I know this has been [a sore issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive/368339#368339https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive/368339#368339https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive/368339#368339) to discuss, and still is. I was glad to see "member since" come back on our user profiles, and this is a good opportunity to express gratitude towards SE for making the effort to put it back on request. I was particularly keen on the "last seen" metrics, which ideally would give the user the option of making it visible or hide it to other users. I have expressed why [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368339/1038222).

My question is: Could staff tell us if they are considering it? Is it something we could expect in the future, or is it a decided matter and things will stay as they are now (without the "last seen" information). I would just like to know what future will bring, or if I should just stop clicking on the name of users in the hope that I will find this information provided again?

Comment: Oh, will they employees read this question then?

Comment: it's possible, but the possibility isn't the same as the employees responding to it.

Comment: Wow, the speed of closing... in seconds! Sorry, but the duplicate doesn't tell me if this issue is being addressed or not.

Comment: But if it's going to be addressed, that's where they'd tell us.

Comment: I bet they will post a new post to announce that :)

Comment: @fev they already made a new post, it just doesnt actually address any of the concerns.

Comment: @KevinB Would you be so kind as to pass me the link?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368661/additional-profile-refinements been kinda radio silence there for a bit.

Comment: Hooray indeed! The miracle happened and the question was reopened. The new post of the link provided by @KevinB actually states that it is good to _**separate an issue into a new post for a cleaner history**_. Well done! That's what I also wanted.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of the [feature request explicitly dedicated to only this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368870/se-is-a-dating-site-revisit-the-last-seen-field) because there really isn't any value in asking a separate yes/no question on whether it is being considered.