# Pluralization bug in last seen field

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, plurals

The [*last seen* field has been restored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371145) recently with a new granularity. There's a pluralization bug

> Last seen more than 1 year**S** ago

[image: Two "last seen" fields, one saying "Last seen more than 1 years ago" and the other "Last seen more than 2 years ago". A red arrow points to the errant "s" in "1 years".]

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371543/560258)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.

> [image: last seen with correct grammar]

(Taken from [this profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/222688/anderzubi).)